# click function triggering function before event finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've built a dropdown menu that uses a slideUp event if the menu itself or anywhere in the body is clicked:

```
$('html, .currentPage').click(function() { 
    $('.currentMenu').slideUp('fast', function() { myFunction(); });
});
```

I also have a function inside the slideUp event callback.

However, my problem is that the function is being called on html or .currentPage click whether the slideUp event has occurred or not.

How can I make it so the function(); **ONLY** happens if the slideUp event runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('html, .currentPage').click(function() { 
    var $currentMenu = $('.currentMenu');

    if($currentMenu.is(':visible')) { 
        $currentMenu.slideUp('fast', function() { myFunction(); });
    }
});
```

even more

```
$('html, .currentPage').click(function() { 
    var $currentMenu = $('.currentMenu');

    if($currentMenu.is(':visible')) { 
        $currentMenu.slideUp('fast', myFunction);
    }
});
```

You can also optionally use `$currentMenu.css('display') != 'none'` instead of `$currentMenu.is(':visible')`.

The options are suggested based on the actual behaviour of `slideUp()`, described in the official documentation at http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.currentMenu').slideToggle('fast', function() { myFunction(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add class `open` to your menu and `slideUp()` if `hasClass('open')`:

```
if ( $menu.hasClass('open') ) {
    $menu.slideUp('fast', function(){ });
    ...
}
```

Comment: or just `$('.currentMenu').is(':visible')`

Comment: Yeah, that would work too depending on how the menu is styled.

Comment: Not related to how the menu is styled. `slideUp()` hides the menu, so, `:is('visible')` is reliable if your hiding logic is `slideUp()`, which is defined already in the question.